# Discrepancy between best_score_ and highest mean_test_score in cv_results_ of HalvingGridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, gridsearchcv

### Problem

I'm using `HalvingGridSearchCV` in scikit-learn for hyperparameter tuning of an XGBoost model in an `imbalanced-learn` pipeline. I've noticed that the `best_score_` (and consequently `best_params_`) does not align with the highest `mean_test_score` in `cv_results_`. This discrepancy is puzzling to me, especially since it can be substantial in some cases; I initially expected that the `best_score_` would match the highest mean_test_score from `cv_results_`, as this score typically represents the best-performing model.

Is it reasonable to consider the model with the highest mean_test_score in `cv_results_` as a valid choice for deployment instead of `best_estimator_`? What are the trade-offs to consider?

As I can't provide the full pipeline or data I'm sharing the relevant parts of the code:

```py
from imblearn.ensemble import BalancedBaggingClassifier
from imblearn import FunctionSampler
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit

# data
X, y = ...

model = Pipeline([
        ('sampling', FunctionSampler(
            ...
        )),
        ('classification', BalancedBaggingClassifier(
            base_estimator=XGBClassifier(
                            eval_metric='aucpr', use_label_encoder=False)
         ))
    ])

params = {
            'classification__base_estimator__max_depth': [3, 5, 7, 10],
            'classification__base_estimator__gamma': [0., 1e-4, 1e-2, 0.1, 1.]
        }

cv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5)
clf = HalvingGridSearchCV(
            estimator=model,
            param_grid=params,
            scoring='average_precision',
            factor=3,
            min_resources=2500,
            cv=cv,
            verbose=1,
            refit=True,
        )
clf.fit(X, y)
```

### Results:

- Best score: 0.3516, Best params: max_depth=10, gamma= 1.
- Highest mean test score: 0.4006, corresponding params: max_depth=7, gamma= 0.1

The combination of parameters corresponding to the *supposedly* best score sometimes doesn't even appear in the top 5 highest mean test scores.

### To sum up:

- Why might the `best_score_` and the highest mean_test_score in `cv_results_` not match, and are there specific criteria or mechanisms in `HalvingGridSearchCV` or XGboost that explain this?
- How should I interpret the discrepancy when selecting the best model for deployment?
  Considering the model with the highest mean_test_score from `cv_results_` as an alternative to `best_estimator_`, what trade-offs should I consider?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. While I can't share the actual data, I can provide additional code snippets or details for context. Thank you!

Comment: A little bit off-topic: Interesting approach of using BBC+XGBC. How does it perform compared to XGBC with scale_pos_weitht set to the classes ratio?

Comment: Regarding your second question: I would always test on a yet unseen validation test set and take these results into account.

Comment: In my case, this performs quite a bit better. I do, however, have a very nosy dataset with a pretty high imbalance. Moreover, I want to leave the option to use the weighing for penalising misclassification severity in the future. Regarding your second point: yes I agree, plan on doing that, thanks; especially considering the implementation of TimeSeriesSplit in sklearn does not even include a validation set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `best_score_` and associated parameters always correspond to the last iteration, i.e. the one with maximum resources. In the [example in the User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#analyzing-results-with-the-cv-results-attribute), the same thing happens: earlier iterations actually have higher mean test score, but those are not taken into consideration for selecting the winner.

Broadly, you do expect the latter iterations to perform better because they have more resources. When the resource is rows (the default), the test folds are also subsampled, which might lead to this situation (the test scores are more noisy, so just be chance are sometimes higher). So I would be hesitant to select a different set of parameters based on earlier iterations.

Comment: Ahh yes, got it. So this is really a consequence of how `HalvingGridSearchCV ` "reports" the results to the `cv_results_`... Naturally, only looking at the mean_test_score column one misses that. Thanks.